Как поймать элемент в HTML?
Всем привет. Подскажите новичку) Есть страница с формой логина. Пишу автотест на нее. При вводе логина и пароля и нажатии на кнопку войти, эта самая кнопка на 1 сек меняется (начинает там кружочек крутиться, вместо текста "Войти"), через devtools вижу что у кнопки меняется class, за который можно зацепиться XPATH-ом. НО! возникает она на 1 сек примерно, и я никак не успеваю скопировать этот класс. Что то мне подсказывает что можно это все дело на паузу поставить в нужный момент? Или есть иные способы? Люди добрые, просветите!

Попробуйте найти элемент в Elements -> ПКМ -> Break On -> attribute modification

Все, нашел решение:

ПКМ на нужный элемент -> Break On -> attribute modification
ставим галочку
Теперь нажимаем на кнопку войти, скрипт ставится на паузу
Во вкладке Sourses в правом окне сверху видим кнопку следующего шага
Нажимаем ее или f8, и элемент меняется.


Теоретически этот способ правильнее моего, ставить и потом удалять эти breakpoint'ы несколько долговато.

Открой вкладку Sources и нажми Ctrl + \ после смены класса. Потом Inspect Element и копируешь свой класс.

# Находим кнопку и нажимаем её
login_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "ваш_XPATH_кнопки")
login_button.click()

# Ожидаем появления элемента с новым классом (кружок загрузки)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "XPath для кнопки с новым классом"))
)

ожидание можно использовать как решение.

в ответе подразумевается ответ, а не вопрос. для уточнящих вопросов есть комментарии

Так вот и вопрос в том как мне XPATH подобрать, если этот элемент(кружок загрузки) на 1 сек появляется и потом обратно в кнопку "Войти" превращается? То есть мне как то в момент этой секунды нужно все на паузу поставить, и подобрать xpath. Но как?

когда включаете режим разработчика в истории не показывает? можете дать ссылку? попробую

@aleksandrbarakin комментарии можно оставлять с 50 репутацией..

https://store.steampowered.com/login/?redir=&redir_ssl=1&snr=1_4_661__global-header
